# Search timeseries value at t + 1 second

Tags: r, time-series, tidyverse, finance

I have two time series dataset, here is a sample of df1:

```
Second_since_midnight  MidPoint        MidPoint2       MidPoint3
34500.041162647        1530.625        1530.555        1530.760
34500.041184315        1530.625        1530.555        1530.760
34500.058515619        1530.620        1530.390        1530.595
34500.069502263        1530.620        1530.390        1530.595
34500.284990991        1530.410        1530.190        1530.395
34500.366234523        1530.410        1530.190        1530.395
34500.366236964        1530.410        1530.185        1530.390
34500.546860111        1529.990        1530.175        1530.175
34500.578238228        1529.855        1530.175        1530.175
34500.890952790        1530.265        1530.190        1530.190
34501.036660390        1530.265        1530.190        1530.190
34501.200413656        1530.265        1530.190        1530.190
```

and df2 is a time series of Second_since_midnight data points which I need to search for 3 midpoints after 1 second:

```
Second_since_midnight  MidPoint_after_1sec MidPoint2_after_1sec Midpoint3_after_1sec
34500.041124224              -1                     -1                  -1
       ...
```

I expect the program to output the following since the first record after 34501.041124224 is the last row in df1 with Second_since_midnight 34501.200413656

```
Second_since_midnight  MidPoint_after_1sec MidPoint2_after_1sec Midpoint3_after_1sec
34500.041124224        1530.265            1530.190             1530.190
       ...
```

I currently write the following R code:

```
    ind_1s = 1

    for(m in 1:nrow(df2)){
        while((df2$Second_since_midnight[m] + 1) > df1$Second_since_midnight[ind_1s] & ind_1s < nrow(df1)) ind_1s = ind_1s + 1
        df2$MidPoint_after_1sec[m] = df1$MidPoint[ind_1s]
        df2$MidPoint2_after_1sec[m] = df1$MidPoint2[ind_1s]
        df2$MidPoint3_after_1sec[m] = df1$MidPoint3[ind_1s]

    }
```

Which is very slow because df2 has an average nrow of 30k and df1 has an average nrow of 1.2m. I wonder if I can have some algorithm that search for this midpoints faster. I'm using R but I can also convert to Python or other languages

Comment: You could use [Rcpp](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html) with the loop above

Comment: You may want to look into `rollapply` and window functions. A for-loop is very inefficient in this case.